# How to send SIGKILL and SIGSTOP to a process on remote shell?

Tags: ssh

There is a program running infinitely on remote shell, which doesn't give me access to its login shell.(i.e, Whenever I login I see that program running on the console).

I wan't send `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP` or `SIGSEGV` etc to stop it via `ssh`.

Is it possible to send and access the normal shell?

Comment: What happens if you press Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-\?

Comment: All the signals are masked by that process. That's why I want these @muru

Comment: How did you end up in this situation? What configuration caused it?

Comment: That program is listed in `/etc/profile` @muru

Comment: If that's the case, have you tried running `ssh -t user@server bash -i`, or `ssh -t user@server vi /etc/profile`?

Comment: @muru `ssh -t ` worked!!. Thanks

Comment: @muru Is there a case where even `ssh -t` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is in `/etc/profile`, note that, over SSH, it is sourced for interactive shells that SSH itself starts. If you run another command, it is not sourced, even if that command is your shell:

```
ssh -t user@server bash
```

When a command is specified, SSH assumes you're not running it interactively, and doesn't allocate a pseudo-tty (which can cause problems with some programs). The `-t` is needed to tell it to allocate a pty anyway.

All of this is moot if your SSH server uses a `ForceCommand` option. If it does, no matter what you specify to the `ssh` command, whatever the server's configured to run will be run.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the login shell for your user is non standard.
Have you tried logging in with `ssh user@host /bin/sh`?  If that works you will be able to figure out the running process and kill it.

Comment: This process is listed in the `/etc/profile`, that's why it didn't give me the access.

Comment: You can disable reading /etc/profile in bash with the --noprofile switch